# Save dataframe to parquet with encrypted columns

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, parquet

I would like to save a dataframe to `parquet` file. However, while writing the data to `parquet` file, I get the following error

```
df.to_parquet(path_to_data + 'data_temp.gzip', compression='GZIP')

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: Expected unicode, got quoted_name
Exception ignored in: 'fastparquet.cencoding.write_list'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/manifests/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastparquet/writer.py", line 1499, in write_thrift
    return f.write(obj.to_bytes())
TypeError: Expected unicode, got quoted_name
```

The same code works in other `dataframes` but this is the first `df` i have worked on which has two encrypted columns.

Any idea how i can fix the issue please.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is by choosing the `engine` type as follows:

```
df.to_parquet(path_to_data + 'data_temp.gzip', compression='GZIP', engine='pyarrow')
```

The file was saved successfully without any error message.

If you have another suggestion, feel free to post it.